# knockout js click binding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, click

I used the example of `knockout js` and its not working. I don't know why click event is not firing.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks"></span> times
    <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
    numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
    incrementClickCounter : function() {
    alert("hi im click");
    var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
    this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);
     }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: what you get error in console?

Comment: when i clicked on button nothing happens

Comment: Please check console... right click on browser...there is option like console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

Comment: now i refreshed and created new view .. now i got nothing on console and the click bind not working... other than jquery and knockout do i need to add any scripts for this to work??

Comment: Activate knockout.js...

Comment: Are you correctly referring to your js files?

Comment: i activated with ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());.... it gave an error on console as Uncaught ReferenceError: ViewModel is not defined..... my references are as  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> and     <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>

Comment: Your `viewModel` starts with low "v" and in code with high "V"

Comment: ya thank and its ko.applyBindings(viewModel);.... it workder for me... thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code
Go Through **[link](http://knockoutjs.com/)**

HTML:

```
<div>
    You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks"></span> times
    <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
    numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
    incrementClickCounter : function() {
    alert("hi im click");
    var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
    this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);
     }
    };

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: thank you prashanth .. ko.applyBindings(viewModel); worked fine